# The concept of app.config file

Tags: vb.net

Could any body kindly advise me about the app.config file.

1. When application is complied, is it copied to Debug (or Release) folder everytime?
2. Does the application reads it at application start up only or on loading each Form?
3. Is there any possibility to re-read it during the run time?

This info will be of great help for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app config does get copied to the Debug / Release folder every time you recompile.  The application can read it whenever your code says to do so, so it can be on load if you choose. And you can re-read it during run time.

I personally have a huge app config for an application I am maintaining.  I love it because you can basically make changes to the program without having to recompile the program.

Example: There are 5 classes a student gets added to when a student is created, those classes are "ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC" etc.  You can change the name of "ClassA" to be say, "ClassroomA", without having to recompile the program and re-distribute.

In addition, you can add or remove classes, so a student will only be added to say 3 classes by default.

...Now of course, that's just a simple example, but App Configs have really solved a lot of trouble for me in the past by taking this approach!

Hope this helps!